# Compile a small subset of the linux kernel (i.e. just a few files)

Tags: c, linux, kernel, compilation

I'm trying to extract specific pieces of code from the linux kernel. I specifically want to compile only a few files, and obviously need to ensure any references and dependencies to other files are included for the compile to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
make fs/read_write.o
make fs/btrfs/
```

For anything else, like `.ko` files, you need to have `System.map` available first, which means having built the core kernel image first (`vmlinux`).